# dnaseq - bad character background color

Tags: color

### how to remove this white box enclosing?

[image: DNA sequence typeset with \DNA!...! with described problem]

Upon changing the page and font color with `xcolor` pkg each letter from `dnaseq`'s `\DNA` command typesets inside a individual white box (or whatever is defined as `white` in the color scheme).

Checking the code inside [the dnaseq pkg pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/dnaseq/dnaseq.pdf) a color definition can be found: `\@DNA@thecolor` defining as `white`, but nothing changes if we re-define with `\def\@DNA@thecolor{...}` after the package requirement.

#### Code for above's picture

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{black}{HTML}{121430}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FEF3D6}

\pagecolor{black}
\color    {white}

% % Bio
\usepackage{dnaseq}
\def\@DNA@thecolor{black} % changes nothing

\begin{document}

\DNA! GCAT GTCA ATTG GGCC TATA TGGC GTAG CAAT TTGG CCGG CTAT ATGG CCGT AGC !

\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: `\def\@DNA@thecolor`  defines the command `\@` not `\@DNA@thecolor` surround by `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, using `\makeatletter\def\@DNA@thecolor{background}\makeatother` instead of just the definition, yeah now i can change the color, but it still doesnt remove the box, is it possible to define an empty/fully transparent color?

Comment: I would expect that produces an error `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color \`background'.` ? There is no color `background`, use `black` as I show below

Comment: Ah my mistake, i used `black` on the code but wrote `background` in the comment. it does "remove" the color, but in instance where i have a different background like when i use `tcolorbox` pkg it becomes an issue again

Comment: You also used `background` in your code in the question. The package unconditionally uses `\colorbox{\@DNA@thecolor}` you could edit that to use `\mbox` instead (the whole package is only a few lines)

Comment: Ah well, yeah i could do that, how do i do it? where can i find the file?

Comment: your document log shows the full path. here /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dnaseq/dnaseq.sty  copy that to document folder and edit, or just do  ...  `{\renewcommand\colorbox[1]{\mbox} \DNA! GCAT GTCA ATTG GGCC TATA TGGC GTAG CAAT TTGG CCGG CTAT ATGG CCGT AGC !}`

Comment: I did something similar, found the `.sty` file and duplicated to my personal packages folder as `mydnaseq.sty`, changed to `\mbox` and now the box is finally removed. thank you.

Also could you kindly update your answer with this solution so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`\def\@DNA@thecolor`  defines the command `\@` not `\@DNA@thecolor` You could surround by `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`, but avoid `\def` in latex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{black}{HTML}{121430}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FEF3D6}

\pagecolor{black}
\color    {white}

% % Bio
\usepackage{dnaseq}

\ExpandArgs{c}\renewcommand{@DNA@thecolor}{black}

\begin{document}

\DNA! GCAT GTCA ATTG GGCC TATA TGGC GTAG CAAT TTGG CCGG CTAT ATGG CCGT AGC !

\end{document}
```

---

The package unconditionally uses `\colorbox{\@DNA@thecolor}` you could edit that to use `\mbox` instead (the whole package is only a few lines)

Your document log shows the full path. Here

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dnaseq/dnaseq.sty
```

Copy that to the document folder or a folder in your input path (preferably renamed as say `mydnaseq.sty`) and edit to replace `\colorbox{..}{..}` by `\mbox{...}`.

---